# Differentiate TypeScript subclasses elegantly

Tags: typescript

I have an application with various kinds of IDs that I pass around as ID objects to enforce type safety. I now want to inherit from the ID base class to differentiate between various kinds of IDs and would like TypeScript to check whether I use the right ID with the right functions and variables. Consider the example below:

```js
class Id {
    id: string

    constructor(id: string) {
        // enforce invariants here or throw

        this.id = id
    }
}

class VideoId extends Id {
    constructor(id: string) {
        super(id)
    }
}

class UserId extends Id {
    constructor(id: string) {
        super(id)
    }
}

function checkUser(userId: UserId) {
    console.log("It's a user!")
}
const videoId = new VideoId("dQw4w9WgXcQ")

// Should be illegal but works!
checkUser(videoId)
```

The point of the subclasses is to leverage the type checking and prevent calls to `checkUser` with anything other than a `UserId` as an argument. [However, since TypeScript will allow any structurally identical object as a class instance,](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#relationships-between-classes) the above example compiles.

How do I differentiate the subclasses from the main class with the least boilerplate possible? Ideally, the added code would not appear in the compiled JavaScript and just impact type checking, so I may be looking for something similar to [Rust's `PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html).

Comment: Well, you can put a distinguishing property in each subclass like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgZnBW), and if you don't want the JS to be affected you can make it a phantom property like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY4A2m) but I don't know if this counts as "the least boilerplate possible".  Let me know if this suffices and I if should write up an answer, or if that's not acceptable and why.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely a solution worthy of an answer. The only thing I do not like here is that the string has to be adjusted manually. Ideally, the line would not be different between the two subclasses, but I'm not sure whether that's possible.
A man can dream I suppose.

Comment: checkUser(videoId) would be illegal if the VideoId class had a property that UserId did not have. Do you want to create multiple types of ID if they all have the same properties?

Comment: Well I see that there are already answers here, and the only thing I can imagine that's better would be to put the string in the parent class and make the class generic.  You still need to write a string for each class, but it would be only the string (like `class X extends Id<"X">`).  I won't bother writing it up because it's similar to the existing answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jcalz in the comments for the `declare` idea, I came up with this fairly clean solution with no runtime impact:

```
class Id<Type extends string> {
    id: string
    declare readonly __type: Type

    constructor(id: string) {
        // enforce invariants here or throw

        this.id = id
    }
}

class VideoId extends Id<'video'> {}

class UserId extends Id<'user'> {}

function checkUser(userId: UserId) {
    console.log("It's a user!")
}
const videoId = new VideoId("dQw4w9WgXcQ")

// Error! Type '"video"' is not assignable to type '"user"'.
checkUser(videoId)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some distinguishable attribute type between the subclass of `Id`. The easiest solution I'd go for would be to define a `IdType` enum, use it on `Id` parent class as `type: IdType` field and narrow typing on sub-classes like this:

```js
enum IdType {
  Video,
  User,
}

class Id {
  id: string;
  type: IdType;

  constructor(id: string) {
    // enforce invariants here or throw

    this.id = id;
  }
}

class VideoId extends Id {
  type: IdType.Video = IdType.Video;

  constructor(id: string) {
    super(id);
  }
}

class UserId extends Id {
  type: IdType.User = IdType.User;

  constructor(id: string) {
    super(id);
  }
}

function checkUser(userId: UserId) {
  console.log("It's a user!");
}

const videoId = new VideoId('dQw4w9WgXcQ');
const userId = new UserId('dQw4w9WgXcQ');

// valid
checkUser(userId);
// invalid
checkUser(videoId);
```